# UISwitch state in Tableviewcell resets when user scrolls - Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uiswitch

I've searched for a solutions on this issue but none seem to work for my use case.

I have a table inside a viewcontroller and the issue I am facing is that when scrolling the UISwitch state is reset to OFF. I understand table cells are reused, but how do I implement a solution that will restore the state of UISwitch when a user scrolls based on my code below

```
import UIKit

class StirrViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var mylabel: UILabel!
var myString = String()

@IBAction func stirrBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
}

var timeSelected = String()
var selectedTimeArr = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mylabel.text = myString
    self.timeSelected = myString
}

func switchChanged(_ sender : UISwitch!){
    print("table row switch Changed \(sender.tag)")
    print("The switch is \(sender.isOn ? "ON" : "OFF")")
    let kValue = (sender.tag + 1)
    let keyValue = String(kValue)
    if sender.isOn {
        recipeSettings.boolStirrSwitch[keyValue] = true
        recipeSettings.switchedOnArr.append(keyValue)

    } else {
        recipeSettings.boolStirrSwitch[keyValue] = false
    }
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    let stringNum = Int(self.timeSelected)
    recipeSettings.recipeTimeSet2 = stringNum!
    return(stringNum)!
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    //here is programatically switch make to the table view
    let switchView = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
    switchView.setOn(false, animated: true)
    switchView.tag = indexPath.row // for detect which row switch Changed
    switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    cell.accessoryView = switchView

    // Process data displayed in rows(minutes)
    let endTime = Int(self.timeSelected)
    let startTime = Int(1)

    // Recipe time array
    let timeArray: [Int]  = Array(startTime...endTime!)
    let stringTimeArr = timeArray.map{String($0)}

    // Save time array to global variable
    recipeSettings.recipeTimeSetArr = stringTimeArr

    // Create a boolean Array to hold all default false booleans
    let defBool: Bool = false
    var defBoolArr: [Bool] = []

    // Fill the array with the defaults boolean
    for _ in 0..<stringTimeArr.count{defBoolArr.append(defBool)}

    // Map the array to global dictionary containing the Time in an array and default "false" value

    for i in 0..<stringTimeArr.count {
        recipeSettings.boolStirrSwitch[stringTimeArr[i]] = defBoolArr[i]
    }

    // Add the minutes to cell table
    cell.textLabel?.text = stringTimeArr[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

As you can see in my code I do save the state of each UI switch in a global variable dictionary. How can I solve the issue of UISwitch changing states based on this code? All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: try this Set the SwitchView State as you saved in recipeSettings.boolStirrSwitch with it's tag Value

Comment: `if let switchState = recipeSettings.boolStirrSwitch[indexPath.row + 1]{
            if switchState{
                switchView.isOn = true
            }else{
                switchView.isOn = false
            }
        }else{
            switchView.isOn = false
        }`

Comment: @GovindKumawat Thanks for response. I have tried that code within the `cellForRowAt`. Im getting an "Ambiguous reference to member subscript" error.

Comment: can u show where u define recipeSettings.boolStirrSwitch?

Comment: // Fill the array with the defaults boolean. in your `cellForRowAt` will again over and over change ur switch state to `let defBool: Bool = false` `false`  so do it in another method then reload table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var switchState = [String : Bool]()
```

- your `recipeSettings.boolStirrSwitch` should be decleard like that.
- As you are using `timeSelected` as `numberOfRowsInSection` as showing
  your cell.textLabel from that so you don't need extra `stringTimeArr`
  for that.
- All the processing you do in `cellForRowAt` it will happen again and
  again table cells are reused so for setting up data do it in another
  `function` then `reload` `TableView`.

Solution for your problem should be look like that.

```
import UIKit

class StirrViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

//make tableView IBOutlet for reloading data
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var mylabel: UILabel!
var myString = String()

@IBAction func stirrBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
}

var timeSelected = String()
var selectedTimeArr = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mylabel.text = myString
    self.timeSelected = myString
    self.setdefaultSwitchState()
}

//recipeSettings.boolStirrSwitch should be decleard like that
var switchState = [String : Bool]()

//setDeaultSwitchState
func setdefaultSwitchState(){
    if let timeSelected = Int(self.timeSelected){
        for value in 0..<timeSelected{
            switchState["\(value)"] = false
            //or
            //recipeSettings.boolStirrSwitch["\(value)"] = false
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


@objc func switchChanged(_ sender : UISwitch!){
    print("table row switch Changed \(sender.tag)")
    print("The switch is \(sender.isOn ? "ON" : "OFF")")
    let kValue = (sender.tag + 1)
    let keyValue = String(kValue)
    if sender.isOn {
        switchState[keyValue] = true

    } else {
        switchState[keyValue] = false
    }
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    let stringNum = Int(self.timeSelected)
    recipeSettings.recipeTimeSet2 = stringNum!
    return(stringNum)!
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    //here is programatically switch make to the table view
    let switchView = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
    switchView.setOn(false, animated: true)
    switchView.tag = indexPath.row // for detect which row switch Changed
    switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    cell.accessoryView = switchView


    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
    if let switchState = switchState["\(indexPath.row)"] {
        if switchState{
            switchView.isOn = true
        }else{
            switchView.isOn = false
        }
    }else{
        switchView.isOn = false
    }

    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks yet again for a more detailed answer. Im almost there. I have had to change `self.tableView.reloadData()` to `self.tableView?.reloadData()` as I was getting `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` error. But now its got strange behaviour when, when user scrolls the state of every cell is reloaded except the first cell. It always resets it to OFF even when initially selected to be ON

Comment: Show your `StirrViewController` update your question let me see how far you have gone through.

Comment: in `func switchChanged(_ sender : UISwitch!)` when switch state changes `let kValue = (sender.tag + 1)` it will always miss that state of first cell always change it to `let kValue = (sender.tag)`